# oracle database 12cR1: Tablespace point in time recovery is failing on the export metadata level

Tags: oracle, rman

I have a problem using TSPITR to restore a single tablespace.
the error stack showed the following:

```
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of recover command at 06/15/2017 20:09:35
RMAN-06962: Error received during export of metadata
RMAN-06960:    EXPDP> ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31637: cannot create job TSPITR_EXP_yhqe_Erry for user SYS
ORA-39062: error creating master process DM00
ORA-31613: Master process DM00 failed during startup.
```

I'm using the fully automated TSPITR method and it is failing on the level when rman initiate export metadata after full recovery of the auxiliary db and creating the datapump directory. please help.

Comment: "Fully automated Method" : you're using Enterprise Manager ? our going directly through RMAN?. If you're using Enterprise Manager, try login using system user.

Comment: Fully automated method is using only the recover script and everything else rman handles it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we solved the issue. we increased the number of processes of the auxiliary instance and then the export started and the tablespace is successfully restored.